# How Threads are stop

Tags: android, multithreading

```
public void onGenerate3() {
    Log.i("onGenerate", "WorkingStart");
```

// thread is used for recursion

```
    myActivity.myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                myActivity.myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(myActivity.GenerateBallonsForTargetScene);
                Log.i("onGenerate", "WorkingEnd");
    }, 1000);
}
```

//Now i Want to stop the thread on a particler action how i can do this

Comment: just put a return statement in run method on condition == true

Answer (score 0):

You won't stop a thread, what you want to do is to cancel the execution of a timed runnable.

I think [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29) is a method to do it.

```
Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    myActivity.myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(myActivity.GenerateBallonsForTargetScene);
    Log.i("onGenerate", "WorkingEnd");
}

// schedule the runnable
myActivity.myHandler.postDelayed(myTask, 1000);

// cancel the runnable
myActivity.myHandler.removeCallbacks(myTask);
```

Of course you can also prevent execution of the code:

```
// member variable
private boolean canceled;

Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    if (!canceled){
      myActivity.myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(myActivity.GenerateBallonsForTargetScene);
      Log.i("onGenerate", "WorkingEnd");
    }
}

// schedule the runnable
myActivity.myHandler.postDelayed(myTask, 1000);

// cancel
canceled = true;
```

Comment: it works for me butt the issue is after this application force close and the error is "exiting thread uncatching exception"